# rabbitmq cluster join does not work

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a rabbitmq cluster with 2 nodes. Node A and B. Node A is up and running. Everytime I run the following commadn on **node A** I get:

```
./rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@A ...
[{nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@A,rabbit@B]}]},
 {running_nodes,[rabbit@A]},
 {partitions,[]}]
...done.
```

Interestingly **node B** is up and running. Everytime I have it join the other node (A) to get it clustered it states:

```
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@A
...done (already_member).

rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@B ...
[{nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@B]}]}]
...done.
```

So somehow node A cannot see B. And on be the "already_member" does not seem to be reflected from the cluster_status command...

I can check the queues on both nodes and they are different. Node A has dozens of queues and node B none, therefore it is clear the cluster is not established. Both node A and B can ping each other and nothing gets reported in the rabbitmq's logs

Any idea how this is not working ?

Answer (score 2):

In case of cluster I will suggest you to go for **Load Balancer** . Make sure you already set **HA Policy** for your cluster.

To set HA Policy

```
$ rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
```

More here [RabbitMQ Cluster](http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/tutorials/how-to-creating-highly-available-message-queues-using-rabbitmq)

Comment: that link is broken

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this same problem. Given **NodeA** is the parent and **NodeB** is trying to join the cluster.

1. Stop **NodeB** app `rabbitmqctl stop_app`
2. On **NodeA** forget cluster node `rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@NodeB`
3. Reset **NodeB** `rabbitmqctl reset`
4. Join **NodeB** to the cluster `rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@NodeA`
5. Start **NodeB** `rabbitmqctl start_app`